# Filtering cells with HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can I make the search functionnality, of jQuery DataTables plugin, ignore HTML tags inside  table cells.
Example : consider a cell containing the string "

```
Hello
```

", when I type "Hello", nothing returned

Answer (score 0):

Use `sType` or `mData` option. Here is example from datatables api http://datatables.net/usage/columns#mData , http://datatables.net/usage/columns#sType:

if you just want to strip html tags when filtering use sType :

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
      { "sType": "html", ... } // column[0] settings
    ]
```

for complex value editing in your `aoColumnDefs` definition use `mData` on column that you want to filter :

```
"mData": function ( source, type, val ) {
        if (type === 'set') { 
          source.<data> = val;
          // Store the computed dislay and filter values for efficiency
          source.<data>_display = ...; // value to be display
          source.<data>_filter  = ...; // value for filtering
          return;
        }
        else if (type === 'display') {
          return source.<data>; // example source.price
        }
        else if (type === 'filter') {
          return source.<data>_filter; // this si that you are looking for.
        }
        // 'sort', 'type' and undefined all just use default value
        return source.<data>;
      }
```

This is solution if you get data in JSON format.

Comment: I have no data in Json Format, I thought it is more simple :(.. Thank you anyway

Comment: use `sType` and set it to "html" for all columns. Look at example in my post